# Fallback case handling using Microsoft Application Logging Block during runtime C#

Tags: c#, logging, enterprise-library, enterprise-library-5

Please let me know your thoughts on the below query,

During runtime, if I have to change the path where logs are written to a default path, how to implement the same using Microsoft Logging Application Block?

Assume, I'm writing the logs to a shared drive. Network is lost. From then on, I have to redirect the log writing process to my local path.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use special sources `Logging Errors & Warnings` as a fallback configuration.

Your configuration normally logs to a shared file trace listener. Additionally, when you configure a `specialSource` for `Logging Errors & Warnings`, it will first try to log to your shared file trace listener, if it fails, it will fallback to this flat file trace listener as you configured in `Logging Errors & Warnings` section.

For example:

```xml
<specialSources>
    <!-- other configurations related with unprocessed categories or all events can be placed here -->
    ....
    <!-- this will be in action when an error occurs during logging -->
    <errors switchValue="All" name="Logging Errors & Warnings">
     <listeners>
      <add name="Local File Trace Listener" />
     </listeners>
    </errors>
```

You can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203279.aspx#config_specialtraces) and [here](http://www.education.vic.gov.au/devreskit/appdev/application%20blocks/logging/logging-standards-details.htm) for more information.

Comment: This solution doesn't work once the network path is unavailable nothing is happening from what configured in <specialSources>